# Check files before commit and extract some in separate commit

Tags: git

I would like to automate the separation of `package-lock.json` into a separate commit.

My idea is to allow the developers to be able to add everything they want including the `package-lock.json`, but on commit to automatically create 1 commit for `package-lock.json` and another for the rest of the changes.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Granted, I don't really have much experience with them, but you might try pre-commit hooks. I used to use them for checking commit messages, but it seems that they can do much more than that: https://githooks.com/

Comment: You can use git hooks for this purpose, take a look on this answer how to filter out certain files form commit and use it to create your new commit.

Comment: Which answer :?